# Using onresume function in gcmintentservice.java

Tags: java, android, ionic-framework, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

Problem :
When the app is open and we get notification and on click of the notification i'am redirecting the user to the respective page. i need the onclick event of notification in [GCMIntentService.java](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/6f497e7b9ee6dc0d2839e2ff797cfd79) file

I have built a chat app in ionic. Having multiple groups. Now i have used hashmap to increment my count when messages come from different groups and i show text like You have X unread message in XXXX group

I want to use the on resume function which is there in platforms/android/src/com/plugin/gcm/PushHandlerActivity.java

```
 @Override
  protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    final NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.cancelAll();
    hmap = new HashMap<Integer, String>();

  }
```

in platforms/android/src/com/plugin/gcm/GCMIntentService.java so when a push notification is clicked i reinitialize the hash map and the count starts from 0

This is my [GCMIntentService.java](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/6f497e7b9ee6dc0d2839e2ff797cfd79) will help anyone who needs to do similar kind of functionality

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how i achieved this.. In your PushHandlerActivity file you need to clear the hashmap

```
   /*
         * this activity will be started if the user touches a notification that we own. 
         * We send it's data off to the push plugin for processing.
         * If needed, we boot up the main activity to kickstart the application. 
         * @see android.app.Activity#onCreate(android.os.Bundle)
         */
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            Log.v(TAG, "onCreate");

            boolean isPushPluginActive = PushPlugin.isActive();
            processPushBundle(isPushPluginActive);

            finish();
            GCMIntentService.hmap.clear();
            if (!isPushPluginActive) {
                forceMainActivityReload();
            }
        }
```